# How can I force minicom to wait to connect to a non-existent device?

Tags: minicom

Occasionally I'm trying to debug a (usually serial) device that starts very quickly.

If I get the device running, I can connect to it using:

`minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0`

Then, if the device disconnects, minicom stays open until it reconnects.

**Is there a switch to tell minicom to open in this "waiting" state, even if the device has not yet been created?**

I've tried `-o` (Do not initialize.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want to do initially is capture all the output from the device you can use:

```
tail -F /dev/ttyUSB0
```

as this will wait until the device exists then read from it. If the device disappears and reappears, it will valiantly re-open it.

---

You can try creating a **fifo** and using minicom on this as the device.
Then, in a loop, wait for the real device to appear, and open and connect it the fifo when it does, for example with **socat**.
minicom will not see the re-opens.

```
mkfifo ~/myfifo
while sleep 1; do socat /dev/ttyUSB0,b19200,echo=0,raw ~/myfifo; done &
minicom -o -D ~/myfifo
```

`b19200` is an example of setting the speed, which you can remove if it doesn't need to be set.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't allow me to interact with the device, merely to read it. :-(

Comment: @tudor I added a socat/fifo example for bidirectional use.

Comment: Ah!  That's a smart way to think about it. :-)

Comment: This looked like a good idea, but didn't work in Ubuntu 22.04 unfortunately. I got three messages in this sequence: **1.** "tail: cannot open '/dev/ttyACM0' for reading: No such file or directory
**2.** "tail: '/dev/ttyACM0' has appeared;  following new file"
**3.** tail: /dev/ttyACM0: cannot seek to offset 0: Illegal seek"